# How can I update a column if another one is empty (but not NULL)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table in **SQLite**:

```
clients
-----------------
id
name
coords
waypoint
```

And whenever I set a **waypoint** for a **client**, I want to ensure that if they don't have any value in column **coords** (I mean, empty value), this will take the same value as in column **waypoint**.

This is a sample of how I most approached the solution, but it will not work if there is already any value in coords:

```
UPDATE clients SET waypoint = '39.232,0.2323', coords = IFNULL(NULLIF(LENGTH(coords), 0), '39.232,0.2323') WHERE id=1
```

In case **coords** had already a value, like '38.09107838452561,-3.788372494    ', it is updated to '30'. Why is that?

**SQLite** is limited, so there are simple functions in other SQL engines that I can't use here.

Comment: The real reason why coords got updated to 30 is that the functionality of NULLIF was misunderstood: NULLIF() returns the value of the 1st parameter unless that value matches the value of the 2nd parameter, in which case it returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case coords had already a value, like
>   '38.09107838452561,-3.788372494', it is updated to '30'. Why is
>   that?

Because the length of the string `'38.09107838452561,-3.788372494'` is `30`.
`NULLIF(LENGTH(coords), 0)` returns `30` since `30 <> 0`.
Finally `IFNULL(NULLIF(LENGTH(coords), 0)` returns `30` since `NULLIF(LENGTH(coords), 0)` is not `null`.
I think what you need is this:

```
UPDATE clients 
SET waypoint = '39.232,0.2323', 
    coords = CASE
      WHEN coords IS NULL OR coords = '' THEN '39.232,0.2323' 
      ELSE coords
    END
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Does it work in SQLite? I didn't find CASE/THEN in its documentation https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/ section "SQLite control flow functions"

Comment: Thank you! I thought I couldn't use that.

Comment: By the way, to make it work just as I needed, I had to modify your query a little:
**"WHEN coords IS NULL OR coords = '' THEN '39.232,0.2323' "** 
because coords may be an empty string, not necessarily NULL.

Comment: Fine. I also edited my answer to meet this requirement too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE()` for this:

```
UPDATE clients
    SET waypoint = '39.232,0.2323',
        coords = COALESCE(coords, '39.232,0.2323')
    WHERE id = 1;
```

EDIT:

If by "empty value" you mean a zero-length string, then just modify the logic:

```
        coords = COALESCE(NULLIF(coords, ''), '39.232,0.2323')
```

Comment: Not in this case because coords = '' (empty string), it is not NULL, so it would take the empty string again.